# How to identify unused libraries and peer dependencies in angular app?

Tags: angular, node-modules

I've a angular application which depends on lot of angular libraries. Now the app code changed over the time and some of the libraries and their peer-dependencies are not referenced anymore.

I want to remove all non-referenced libs from package.json.

Is there a way to identify all the libs and peer-deps which are not required ?

Comment: Run npm prune to remove modules not listed in package.json.

Comment: @Hamza Thanks for the advice but I want to remove libs which are in package.json and not referenced in the app not just from node_modules folder

Comment: Have you check installing this 1. npm install depcheck -g
2. depcheck

Comment: SourceMapExplorer may be helpful to you